# Is it possible to get the exit code from a subshell?

Tags: bash, scripting, exit-code

Let's imagine I have a bash script, where I call this:

```
bash -c "some_command"
do something with code of some_command here
```

Is it possible to obtain the code of `some_command`? I'm not executing `some_command` directly in the shell running the script because I don't want to alter it's environment.

Comment: I'm not sure about your reasons for executing indirectly - that subshell does inherit the environment from the calling script. Just try `export FOO="foo"; bash -c 'echo $FOO'` (single quotes so it's not expanded until subshell runs it).

Comment: It does inherit the environment, but it won't modify the environment for the current shell. Any modification it will make to the env. vars will be gone when it dies.

Comment: If you want to run something without mucking up the parent shell then I'd use a subshell, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`$?` will contain the return code of `some_command` just as usual.

Of course it might also contain a code from bash, in case something went wrong before your command could even be executed (wrong filename, whatnot).

Comment: Note however that 
`local var=$(command)` 
will NOT return the exit code.  Instead you need to do `local var;  var=$(command)`

Comment: Excellent answer (works for me). But why? 

Comment: @TimPotapov "The exit status of the command is overridden by the exit status of the creation of the local variable" from [SC2155](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2155#problematic-code-in-the-case-of-local)

Comment: OMG the number of hours I've wasted on this over time...thank you so much @LukeH

Answer (score 36):

Here's an illustration of `$?` and the parenthesis subshell mentioned by **Paggas** and **Matti**:

```
$ (exit a); echo $?
-bash: exit: a: numeric argument required
255
$ (exit 33); echo $?
33
```

In the first case, the code is a Bash error and in the second case it's the exit code of `exit`.

Comment: Don’t you mean `$(…)`, and not `$ (…)` ? The latter is not only invalid, but also very confusing.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: The dollar sign is the prompt in this case. It's not meant to be typed. The bare parentheses set up a subshell as mentioned in my answer ans allow you to get the exit code and not actually exit the main shell.

Comment: Ah. Still makes things confusing. Not your fault though that the standard prompt is the same as the variable indicator. :)

Comment: In my case I'm after the exit code from a subshell used in an assignment, which hides the subshell code: `RESULT=(exit 33); echo $?; echo $RESULT` returns: `0` and `exit`.

Comment: @J0hnG4lt: You're missing a dollar sign (what you did is create an array consisting of the strings "exit" and "33"). A command substitution would look like: `result=$(exit 33)`, but that still doesn't work to save the code in the variable. This is what you need to do: `(exit 33); result=$?` Note that I used a lower case variable name. It's better not to use all-caps variable names in order to avoid possible collisions with shell and environment variables.

Comment: Sorry: fish shell syntax.   Updating.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `$?` variable, check out the bash documentation for this, it stores the exit status of the last command.

Also, you might want to check out the bracket-style command blocks of bash (e.g. `comm1 && (comm2 || comm3) && comm4`), they are always executed in a subshell thus not altering the current environment, and are more powerful as well!

EDIT: For instance, when using ()-style blocks as compared to bash -c 'command', you don't have to worry about escaping any argument strings with spaces, or any other special shell syntax. You directly use the shell syntax, it's a normal part of the rest of the code.

Comment: In other words, `(some_command)` instead of `bash -c "some_command"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for

```
$ RESULT=`echo Hello; exit 33`; echo ${PIPESTATUS}; echo $RESULT
33
Hello
```